# Get realtime updates with Cloud Firestore - Flutter

Tags: flutter

i tried some sentences condition for my code but it not working, when i run it, it show "There is no jobs". I want to show my list into display. i don't know i have error about condition or shomething! Please help

```
body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('jobs')
      .where('jobCategory', isEqualTo: jobCategoryFilter)
      .where('recruitment', isEqualTo: true)
      .orderBy('createdAt', descending: false)
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot)
  {
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
    {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
    }
    else  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active)
    {
      if(snapshot.data.docs.length > 0){
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return JobWidget(
                jobTitle: snapshot.data?.docs[index]['jobTitle'],
                jobDescription: snapshot.data?.docs[index]['jobDescription'],
                jobId: snapshot.data?.docs[index]['jobId'],
                uploadedBy: snapshot.data?.docs[index]['uploadedBy'],
                userImage: snapshot.data?.docs[index]['userImage'],
                name: snapshot.data?.docs[index]['name'],
                recruitment: snapshot.data?.docs[index]['recruitment'],
                email: snapshot.data?.docs[index]['email'],
                location: snapshot.data?.docs[index]['location'],
              );
            }
        );
      }
      else
      {
        return const Center(
          child: Text('There is no jobs'),
        );
      }
    }
    return const Center(
      child: Text(
        'Something went wrong',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 30
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

i tried to upload this list into display but it not! Please help

Comment: It looks good to me, you already added some documents within the collection that have those parameters?

Comment: instead of snapshot.data.docs.length you can just use snapshot.hasData